# Naming: How to call a direct product of elementary abelian groups?

Tags: group-theory, notation

Is there an accepted name for abelian groups of the form $\prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{Z}_{p_i}$ for some primes $p_1,\dotsc,p_n$?
(i.e: direct products of cyclic groups of prime orders, or in other words - direct products of elementary abelian groups).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the primes are distinct, these are the cyclic groups of square-free order.

If the primes are not distinct, these are the abelian groups of square-free [exponent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponent_%28group_theory%29).

Comment: On the other hand, *direct product of elementary abelian groups* is just as good, if not better.